# Connect mysql workbench to GCE mysql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, connection, mysql-workbench

It's been two days and I've given up on this. I'm unable to connect to my google compute engine running mysql using workbench.

I've followed instructions on numerous stackoverflow links to no avail. See below status of everything.

Below is executed on the GCE via ssh browser window.

```
lunchbusters_za@lamp-inst:~$ cat /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf | grep bind
```

**bind-address            = 0.0.0.0**

Note I've also commented out above bind-address.

```
lunchbusters_za@lamp-inst:~$ netstat -an | grep 3306
```

**tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN**

```
lunchbusters_za@lamp-inst:~$ sudo ufw status
```

**Status: inactive**

Firewall not even enabled, but I have allowed 3306/tcp anyway.

Below is the user I'm using, it can connect. I've set password to NO just to rule that out.

```
lunchbusters_za@lamp-inst:~$ mysql -u admin
```

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

**Now I want to use workbench which is running on my Macbook to connect to the GCE:**

I take the external IP from the Google Cloud Platform dashboard for my VM and try to connect using workbench.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not on a private network that could block anything, I'm connected to my private wifi modem.

I can also ping the external IP from my macbook I'm trying to connect from. I can also access phpmyadmin from my local webbrowser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use SSH tunnel to connect:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-a INSTANCE_NAME -- -N -p 3306 -D localhost:3306
```

But let me try help you without a workaround.

So we need to follow these steps:

- **Step 1** - Check the firewall rules - In
  https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/ check if you have a rules for **tcp:3306** or a **tcp** range that includes **3306**.
- **Step 2** - Check local connectivity with **port 3306** - In the same gce instance that you have mysql running test the connectivity using **telnet in the port 3306** (`telnet ip-machine 3306`).
- **Step 3** - Check local connectivity with mysql - From the same instance that you have mysql running connect in mysql.
- **Step 4** - Connectivity inside the GCP network - Execute the previous steps from another GCE Instance in the same GCP project.
- **Step 5** - Connectivity port 3306 outside GCP - Execute the **step 2** from your machine.

Comment: Step 1: There is a rule I created:
mysql-remote-access-Ingress-mysql-server-Tags: mysql-client-tcp:3306-Allow
Step 2: Unable to. Just says Trying…
Step 3: I can connect to mysql on the instance it’s installed.
Step 4: Cannot telnet from another GCE to my existing one. I can however ping it.
Step 5: Cannot telnet from my machine to GCE, but I can ping it.

This seems like some networking issue…

Comment: I created another firewall rule now excluding all the mysql tags, and now I'm connected. Knew it had something to do with the port, but just couldn't put my finger on it. Thanks so much bro! 

port-3306
Ingress
Apply to all 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:3306
Allow
1000

Comment: I glad to help you! Be careful with firewall rules for 0.0.0.0/0 I recommend that you get your ip  using http://whatismyip.host/  and create rules just to accept your ip address

Comment: Will do. Thanks!