# Kibana and elasticsearch status is active , i can access elasticsearch via browser but kibana is giving error

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I installed kibana and elasticsearch on google instance, elasticsearch is working fine. But when hit curl command for kibana it's giving an error message.

```
    curl -X GET "10.128.0.26:9200/"
{
"name" : "node-1",
"cluster_name" : "ElasticsearchStaging",
"cluster_uuid" : "r-A1o-coQlWUWeoXIFa5gw",
"version" : {
"number" : "7.3.0",
"build_flavor" : "default",
"build_type" : "deb",
"build_hash" : "de777fa",
"build_date" : "2019-07-24T18:30:11.767338Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "8.1.0",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

This is the message i am getting for kibana

```
curl -X GET "10.128.0.26:5601/"
Kibana server is not ready yet
```

kibana.log file:

```
07T10:17:47Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:47Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:47Z","tags":["warning","task_manager"],"pid":6590,"message":"PollError No Living connections"}
07T10:17:48Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:48Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:50Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:50Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:50Z","tags":["warning","task_manager"],"pid":6590,"message":"PollError No Living connections"}
07T10:17:51Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:51Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:53Z","tags":["warning","task_manager"],"pid":6590,"message":"PollError No Living connections"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["license","warning","xpack"],"pid":6590,"message":"License information from the X-Pack plugin could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluation from the X-Pack plugin could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster. Error: No Living connections"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
07T10:17:56Z","tags":["warning","task_manager"],"pid":6590,"message":"PollError No Living connections"}
07T10:17:58Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/"}
07T10:17:58Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6590,"message":"No living connections"}
```

This is my kibana.yml file:

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601
# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "10.128.0.26"
# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""
# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false
# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576
# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
server.name: "ironman"
# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://0.0.0.0:9200"]
# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
elasticsearch.preserveHost: true
# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.

kibana.index: ".kibana"
```

also I tried `./bin/kibana`
this is the message i am getting.

```
Kibana should not be run as root. Use --allow-root to continue.
```

after following instruction

```
./bin/kibana --allow-root
```

I got this message:

```
 log   [09:53:13.146] [fatal][root] Error: Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be running!
    at Root.shutdown (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/root/index.js:67:18)
    at Root.setup (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/root/index.js:46:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
 FATAL  Error: Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be running!
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this:

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://10.128.0.26:9200"]
```

Comment: yes I tried but now after running curl command m not getting anything, and another thing that is disturbing me is, how to generate log file in kibana
`logging.dest: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log`
after setting this in yml file , my kibana is stop working

Comment: Ok, but does your Kibana work now?

Comment: sir the thing is if we forget about log for a while then yes kibana status is active, when i run `service kibana status` then its showing active running, but after `curl` command its showing nothing not even an error. Then i try to look into log file that's why i set path in yml file but now kibana is not even active.

Comment: `lsof -i :5601`

`COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    2994 kibana   19u       IPv4  28201      0t0  TCP elastic-stage-vyakar.c.vyakar-staging.internal:5601 (LISTEN)`

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to access kibana via curl. can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually, you are right i don't want to access it using curl, kibana, and elasticsearch both installed in google instance and i want to access them from my local machine using a browser and i succeed with elasticsearch but when i try to access kibana from my browser then its showing time_out message.

So is there any way to solve this, i have been working on this problem very long. May be kibana is not connecting with elasticsearch that can be a reason, if it is, so what can i do for this

Comment: Since the IP address is a private one, you might need to create an SSH tunnel from your workstation to your GCP host in order to access it.

Comment: Okk, but can you tell me how to do that, can you share a link or something that describe the process, because i didn't get it.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025405/4604579

Comment: Actually i made some changes in kibana.yml file and its start working, But thank you for asking you helped a lot

Comment: yes yes obviously. Actually all these elasticsearch thing seems very hard to me i know its easy but still it seems very hard. Right now i am trying to set password to kibana at the time when i access it from browser so can you help me with that.

Comment: I'd say it's a different issue which would require a different question.

Comment: ok i will create one.

Comment: i have created can you please help this is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483664/elasticsearch-stop-working-after-enable-x-pack

Comment: Sure, just close this one, since it's done, please