# Elasticsearch stop working after enable x-pack

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have elasticsearch and kibana 7.3 now what i want when i access kibana from browser it should ask for password or userid then search little about it and came up with this x-pack thing, i set `xpack.security.enabled: true` but now elasticsearch is giving error

this is elasticsearch.yml file

```
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: ElasticsearchStaging
#xpack.security.enabled: true
#xpack.security.audit.enabled: true
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
```

i comment `#xpack.security.audit.enabled: true` because it was giving error.
also my /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log file is not getting update.

if i use `journalctl -u elasticsearch.service` then i get this :

```
Aug 13 18:07:54 elastic-stage-vyakar systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Aug 13 18:07:57 elastic-stage-vyakar elasticsearch[3897]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Aug 13 18:08:21 elastic-stage-vyakar systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Aug 13 18:08:21 elastic-stage-vyakar systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 13 18:18:13 elastic-stage-vyakar systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Aug 13 18:18:15 elastic-stage-vyakar elasticsearch[4164]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Aug 13 18:18:40 elastic-stage-vyakar systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Aug 13 18:18:40 elastic-stage-vyakar systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here is my kibana.yml file :

```
server.port: 5601
# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: 10.***.*.**
# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""
# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false
# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576
# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
server.name: testing
# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: http://10.***.*.**:9200
# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
#elasticsearch.preserveHost: true
# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
kibana.index: kibanaindx
# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "home"
# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
server.name: testing
# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "home"
# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "pass"
# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key
# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files validate that your Elasticsearch backend uses the same key files.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key
# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have your `/var/log/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchStaging.log`. It should indicate the failure that likely occurred during bootstrap. Elasticsearch would fail to start if using the OSS only version since it does not ship with X-Pack.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have that file but the thing is its not getting updated, but if i use `journalctl -u elasticsearch.service` then i am getting updated log, but i want this in file format.

Comment: There are duplicate configuration keys in your original post. Make sure they do not exist in your actual elasticsearch.yml. I would suggest removing the installation and starting again clean. After removing the rpm package, `rm -rf /etc/elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch`. Reinstall the rpm, get the service to run and give the security configuration another go. Ensure you are using the non-OSS Elasticsearch version.